# asp.net mvc routing issues

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I haved added this routing to my global asax.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "News", // Route name
    "News/{timePeriod}/{categoryName}/{page}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "News", action = "Index", 
        timePeriod = TimePeriod.AllTime, categoryName = "All", page = 1 },
    new { page = @"^\d{1,3}$" }// Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "News2", // Route name
    "News/{categoryName}/{page}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "News", action = "Index", 
        timePeriod = TimePeriod.AllTime, categoryName = "All", page = 1 },
    new { page = @"^\d{1,3}$" }// Parameter defaults
);
```

The problem is urls like /News/add wont work (unless i add the specific route)
is there a better way without having to specify url action in global asax?

Comment: BTW, the line you have marked as Paramter Defaults is Parameter Constraints. Parameter defaults are one line higher.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that would catch it. But only, if you won't pass any extra arguments like id (because, then it's very similar to News2 route).

```
routes.MapRoute(
"News0",
"News/{action}",
new { controller = "News", action = "Index" }
);
```

Also, try Routing Debugger to test for effect you want:
[link](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your two routes above will each route to the News controller and hit the "Index" action. If you don't have overloads for the Index action that will take the parameters you are specifying then the route won't work properly.  For instance, you should have these two actions:

```
public ActionResult Index(TimePeriod timePeriod, string categoryName, int page) {..}

public ActionResult Index(string categoryName, int page) {..}
```

Also, you should remove the default parameter of TimePeriod from your second route since you aren't using it in the route itself:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "News2", // Route name
                "News/{categoryName}/{page}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "News", action = "Index", categoryName = "All", page = 1 },
                new { page = @"^\d{1,3}$" }// Parameter defaults
            );
```

I would recommend having an action for every category instead of creating a route for each category. You could simplify your routes to this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "News", // Route name
                "News/{action}/{timePeriod}/{page}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "News", action = "Index", timePeriod = TimePeriod.AllTime, categoryName = "All", page = 1 },
                new { page = @"^\d{1,3}$" }// Parameter defaults
            );
```

Then having an action for each category:

```
public ActionResult All(TimePeriod timePeriod, string categoryName, int page) {..}

public ActionResult Sports(TimePeriod timePeriod, string categoryName, int page) {..}

public ActionResult Weather(TimePeriod timePeriod, string categoryName, int page) {..}
```

This way all you will need is the one route.

Comment: This is nice solution, but maybe reklas does want to have different routes, to make his URLs nicer. For example he doesn't need page for adding news action, but want it, when he is displaying results.

Comment: @kMike - If that is the case he just has to make those paramaters optional in the route and his url's will not have to contain them.